# Is how could I manage delay AWS Eventbridge trigger time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I made a eventbridge evoking every minute to fetch data and save it.

Lmabda that eventbridge evokes consumes around 80mb ~ 90mb and takes around 3000ms ~3500ms (3~3.5 sec)

As you could see, my lambda is triggered at ??:35 sec which I didn't expected

I expected lambda to run every ??:00 like example AWS shows

expected to run at :

05:01:00, 05:02:00, 05:03:00, 05:04:00, ...

reality :

05:01:35, 05:02:35, 05:03:35, 05:04:35, ...

should I start event trigger at ??:00 by my self?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change that, as resolution of EB is 1 minute, not seconds. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html):

> Your scheduled rule runs **within that minute**, but not on the precise 0th second.

Comment: oh, so it's random right?

Comment: @ccppoo Random up to the 1 minute.

Comment: thank you, is there any chance that my event trigger will change? For example like in my case it started at every 35 second then some day it will change to every ??:20 can't find somethin about it

Comment: @ccppoo Forget about seconds. Its only one minute accurate.